# Iframe cause document height to be equal to the window/viewport height on IOS devices (chrome & safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iframe, revolution-slider

I'm trying to embed a website that I don't have control on inside my website.

The issue as the title mentioned I'm facing an infinite scrolling within the iframe. If I try to open the original website it's working. Does anyone know why this happens?

Check this https://revolution.themepunch.com/le-chef-restaurant-website-wordpress-template/ site to see the expected result.
while if you try to load it in an iframe it won't render correctly.
Code:

```
<iframe  src="https://revolution.themepunch.com/le-chef-restaurant-website-wordpress-template/"></iframe>
```

**Updats:
After debugging that page I found there's a strange behavior, which is the document height is equal to the window/view port height, this is the reason of this issue. What might cause a behaviour like this (document height == window height), I cannot find any part of code that modify the window height using API like resizeto or other stuff.**

**Notes:**

1. The size of the loaded website is about 20MB.
2. It opens correctly on Andorid devices.
3. For Iphone if a scrolling animation forked, then my website crashed completely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the exact same problem. Will post an answer once I figure it out. So far none of the posted solutions I've found have worked (probably because I'm an amateur when it comes to CSS).

EDIT (x-post/repost):

Okay, so the answer that I found is that if you set scrolling=no for your iframe, then the bug will go away. Unfortunately the project I'm working on needs to have a scrolling iframe, so that's sort of a problem for me, but I hope this solution helps!

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById("iFrame");
iFrame.scrolling = "no";
```

Comment: Yes, I’m aware of the scrolling workaround. But it’s not abicable. It’s a bug in the revolution lib.They should consider iframe scenario. I hardcoded some height calculation to prove that.